# List event classes for ETW provider

Tags: c, windows, events, etw

I would like to implement an [ETW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx) consumer in `C` for events coming from the `Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP` provider. However, I fail to find the type of event this provider generates.

I already did some similar work to consume events from `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-*` (see [NT Kernel Logger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363691(v=vs.85).aspx)) , but the events sent from this provider were *decently* documented on MSDN (see documentation about [Enable Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363784(v=vs.85).aspx)).

So I guess the real question is: how can I link an ETW provider to the type of events (we are talking about C structures here) that it generates and possibly vice-versa (if feasible at all)?

Thanks!

*Edit 0*: I don't mind using other technologies to find the details about a class. For example, getting the details of the `Registry` class (for the NT Kernel Logger), one would use `powershell` and run the following command (note that you need the right namespace otherwise you won't get the right type):

```
$list = gwmi -namespace root\wmi -Class Registry* -list
foreach($element in $list) {
   ([wmiclass]$element).gettext("mof")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into [TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/)?. It is not in C. It is managed code. But it is nice way to listen to the ETW events.

Comment: I need a C solution unfortunately.